# How to set editEdit input format in specific format

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

How to set editEdit input format in specific format, I want set it to XXXX-XXX-XXX-XXXX(X) in the character format.

I try many way at the textEdit.properties still unable to set it.

Best regards,
Thank you.

Comment: what input string you want to input in the edit control?? what are you trying to set Edit mask or display format.. It is little unclear that what exactly you are trying to achieve. Please show some code of implementation to get answer soon..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you can use the [simple mask](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1500):

```
textEdit1.Properties.Mask.MaskType = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Mask.MaskType.Simple;
textEdit1.Properties.Mask.EditMask = "AAAA-AAA-AAA-AAAA(a)";
```

Mask's etacharacters are:
`A` any alphanumeric character(required)
`a` any alphanumeric character(optional)

Related help article:
[Mask Editors Overview](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument583)